# Numerically solve a system of second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to reproduce the results of [this paper](https://www.scielo.br/j/lajss/a/jHTwkrDzNPtb8yjWWvKMg3M/?lang=en&format=pdf) where a cable is simulated by dividing it into smaller alternating rigid segments (RFE) and spring-damping elements (SDE). The authors go on deriving the Potential, Kinetic and Dissipative contributions and after putting everything together they obtain a system of 2nd order non-linear differential equations:

$$ \ddot{q} = f(\dot{q},q,t) $$

Now I want to simulate this system numerically. Since the function $ f $ is not linear I can't use the approach suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732759/solve-a-system-of-second-order-differential-equations). I can however try [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317393/accurate-way-to-numerically-solve-a-system-of-second-order-odes) approach:

$$ S = \begin{cases} \dot{p} = f(p,q,t) \\ \dot{q} = p \end{cases} $$

Given I am able to rewrite my system $ S $ in this form, what would you use to do the numerical simulation? Can a simple 1st order ODE solver like the one that [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) has work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not used to Python but to its cousin, Matlab. Have you attempted to use (one of) the Runge-Kutta solvers ? It is usually very stable for systems of (first-order) differential equations. More details on request.